# With recursive functions in Go, if the inner function returns, does the outer function continue execution normally?

Tags: recursion, go, dereference, panic

Okay, so I have this piece of code

```
func registerDomain(domainName string, n int) bool {
    //building the request here 
    resp, errr := client.Do(r)
    if errr != nil { 
        if n == 1 {
            return false
        }
        registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
    }

    bodyBytes, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err2 == nil {
        resp.Body.Close()
        //handle bodyBytes
        //if the response is how it should be return true, if it's not call the function again with n-1
    } else { //if there is an error reading the response
        resp.Body.Close()
        if n == 1 {
            return false
        }
        registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
    }
    return false //it should never reach this line
}
```

Explanation:

I call the function with an argument n (let's say 5) that represents the number of times the function will retry if something is not right. Every time something is wrong I make a recursive call with n-1 so when it reaches n=1 it gives up and returns false. This code works fine in practice, it does what it's supposed to do, sometimes when the response is not correct it calls itself recursively and it works the second (or 3rd, 4th..) time around. When the problem isn't fixed before n=1 it returns false.

The problem:

This is a part of a big code that is supposed to run for about 17 hours and it panics when it tries to read from the body sometimes on this line:

```
bodyBytes, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

it says panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference. Now I know that probably means that it's trying to read from a nonexistent resp.Body but the [Go documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do) clearly states that **When err is nil, resp always contains a non-nil resp.Body**.

So, in my head it's probably something with the recursive calls. The *only* thing that makes sense to me is this scenario: lets say that the errr is not nil (this means that the resp.Body doesn't exist), so it goes inside of the if errr != nil and because n!=1, it will call itself again with n=4. Let's say this time everything is as it should be and the second function returns true to the first one **BUT** the first one continues with execution and tries to read from the resp.Body which doesn't exist. That causes panic and here we are...

So, what I need is someone that knows exactly how recursive functions work and if it's not that, can I somehow check the existence of resp.Body before I read form it, or something that will help.

Thanks anyways! :)

**UPDATE:** You were all right, my code doesn't panic anymore and neither do I. Thank you very much! (I'm not sure if this is where the update goes)

Comment: Does it panic immediately, or after some time?

Comment: After a lot of time, about 4 hours of execution. So it must be a really specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `registerDomain()` function there are 2 places where you call itself.

If the `client.Do()` failes (`errr != nil`), you will call `registerDomain()` again. Sometime it will return, and when it does, your code execution will continue, trying to read from `resp.Body` but that most likely is `nil` because `errr != nil`.

Here is how you should handle it:

Whenever you make a recursive call, you should not let code continue when that call returns, but return the value it returned, something like this:

```
return registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
```

### Alternative

The problem you're trying to solve can be solved without recursion using a `for` statement. The `for` variant will even be clearer and more simple.

Modify your `registerDomain()` function to return false at each point it calls itself, and use this loop to retry 5 times:

```
var result bool
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    result = registerDomain(domainName) // You don't need to pass n anymore
    if result {
        break
    }
}

if result {
    fmt.Println("Domain registered successfully!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Failed to register domain!")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to add the return before the registerDomain recursive call and update this post if that was the problem, but I feel confident that this was it because it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
```

to

```
return registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
```

This way outer function will not continue executing and will not read from nil body.

Comment: Yes, this fits perfectly, I will try it and I will update after the execution if this was the solution or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return after your first registerDomain call or you will panic on ioutil.ReadAll when your call to registerDomain finishes

```
//building the request here 
resp, errr := client.Do(r)
if errr != nil { 
    if n == 1 {
        return false
    }
    return registerDomain(domainName, n-1)
}
```

Comment: Well I feel relieved already having in mind that all of the answers (3) currently are suggesting the same thing. Thank you - I will try it and update.